# my html only shows content from script in just one input box

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

So what i want is to display the content on multiple input tabs. 
this is my html body I have tried using i frame but it wont overflow right! I want to display the dropdown of abbreviations please help:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Enter an Airport</label>
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Another field (so we can test TAB behavior)
</label>
<input type="text" />
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/fuse.js@2.5.0/src/fuse.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://screenfeedcontent.blob.core.windows.net/html/airports.js'></script>

<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

this is my style css:

```
enter code herebody {
margin: 50px;
}

.form-group {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.control-label {
display: block;
}

.autocomplete-wrapper {
position: relative;
}
.autocomplete-wrapper input {
width: 100%;
}

.autocomplete-results {
position: absolute;
background: white;
z-index: 1;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
font-size: 13px;
border: solid 1px #ddd;
border-top-width: 0;
border-bottom-color: #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.autocomplete-result {
padding: 12px 15px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
cursor: pointer;
}

.autocomplete-result:last-child {
border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.autocomplete-location {
 opacity: .8;
 font-size: smaller;
 }

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='0'] > :nth-child(1) {
 color: white;
background: #26C9FF;
border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
}

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='1'] > :nth-child(2) {
color: white;
 background: #26C9FF;
border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
}

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='2'] > :nth-child(3) {
 color: white;
background: #26C9FF;
border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
}

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='3'] > :nth-child(4) {
  color: white;
 background: #26C9FF;
 border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
}

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='4'] > :nth-child(5) {
  color: white;
 background: #26C9FF;
border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
}

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='5'] > :nth-child(6) {
 color: white;
background: #26C9FF;
 border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
  outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
 }

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='6'] > :nth-child(7) {
 color: white;
  background: #26C9FF;
 border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
 outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
 }

.autocomplete-results[data-highlight='7'] > :nth-child(8) {
color: white;
background: #26C9FF;
border-bottom-color: #26C9FF;
outline: solid 1px #00b6f2;
}
```

ANd this is my javascript:

```
 var options = {
 shouldSort: true,
 threshold: 0.4,
 maxPatternLength: 32,
 keys: [{
    name: 'iata',
    weight: 0.5
 }, {
    name: 'name',
    weight: 0.3
  }, {
     name: 'city',
   weight: 0.2
  }]
};

var fuse = new Fuse(airports, options)


var ac = $('#autocomplete')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
 })
  .on('focus keyup', search)
  .on('keydown', onKeyDown);

var wrap = $('<div>')
  .addClass('autocomplete-wrapper')
  .insertBefore(ac)
  .append(ac);

var list = $('<div>')
  .addClass('autocomplete-results')
  .on('click', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    selectIndex($(this).data('index'));
  })
  .appendTo(wrap);

$(document)
  .on('mouseover', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
    var index = parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10);
    if (!isNaN(index)) {
      list.attr('data-highlight', index);
    }
  })
  .on('click', clearResults);

function clearResults() {
  results = [];
  numResults = 0;
  list.empty();
}

function selectIndex(index) {
  if (results.length >= index + 1) {
    ac.val(results[index].iata);
    clearResults();
  }  
}

var results = [];
var numResults = 0;
var selectedIndex = -1;

function search(e) {
  if (e.which === 38 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 40) {
    return;
  }

   if (ac.val().length > 0) {
     results = _.take(fuse.search(ac.val()), 7);
     numResults = results.length;

     var divs = results.map(function(r, i) {
         return '<div class="autocomplete-result" data-index="'+ i +'">'
              + '<div><b>'+ r.iata +'</b> - '+ r.name +'</div>'
              + '<div class="autocomplete-location">'+ r.city +', '+ r.country +'</div>'
              + '</div>';
      });

     selectedIndex = -1;
     list.html(divs.join(''))
       .attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);

   } else {
     numResults = 0;
     list.empty();
   }
 }

 function onKeyDown(e) {
   switch(e.which) {
     case 38: // up
       selectedIndex--;
       if (selectedIndex <= -1) {
         selectedIndex = -1;
       }
       list.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);
       break;
     case 13: // enter
       selectIndex(selectedIndex);
       break;
     case 9: // enter
       selectIndex(selectedIndex);
       e.stopPropagation();
       return;
     case 40: // down
       selectedIndex++;
       if (selectedIndex >= numResults) {
         selectedIndex = numResults-1;
       }
       list.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);
       break;

     default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
   }
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
 }
```

what i think is that the problem is in css!
i even tried duplicating the file and functions by some other name and integrate it in another html file but still its not working!

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/xzcqkf4d/](https://jsfiddle.net/xzcqkf4d/)

Comment: I have this working but if u create another field of same input type its not showing me the dropdown! that is my main problem